# SuccessFactors 3rd party integration

Tags: sap-successfactors

Is it possible to hit a custom REST API from SuccessFactors LMS in order to integrate my designed API with SuccessFactors?
If yes, how?
If no, what will be other possible ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify lms api. In sf platform you can work with "manage object definition" to adapt smaller things like association between objects or custom mdf objects.
Lms and its micro services api is way more strict, you can't modify at all.
In your case, if I get you right, you have the option to build a custom Odata service on sap cloud platform integration service. Within this odata service you can combine both apis to achieve one single api. If you provide more details it might be easier to help.